# Ubuntu TV on a pc

Tags: lsusb

Where can I download Ubuntu Tv for pc ?

I have an AMD Sempron computer and 1 gb of ram memory. I want to know if i can install ubuntu tv on that pc. I will thank you to answar me

Answer (score 0):

I would [start here](http://www.ubuntu.com/devices/tv/contact-us) but Ubuntu TV **is not** xbmc, plex, or MythTV. Your probably looking for the wrong thing.

Comment: Ok i will look for other media center

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu TV is still in development. It isn't a Program itself it is a distibution.
And if you use it your machine will slow down.

I can tell that you at least need OpenGL.

Comment: So I can`t install ubuntu tv. :(